# How do I use SSLSockets instead of standard Sockets with Java apps

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I'm trying to use ssl sockets in a working java networking program.

I replaced two lines of code

```
        //Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(ipAddress, port);
```

and

```
        //serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
        serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket();

        serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            ......
```

I get an exception: "connection refused: Connect"

The program was working with the commented code. And now it doesn't. What do I need to do to use SSLSockets instead of standard Sockets ?

If relevant, the server is running on localhost == windows vista.

Comment: What's the full trace of the exception? (And relevant line numbers of your code)

Comment: I get the error exactly at the first line mentioned, when the client tries to connect. The error is just what i wrote, no more.

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example exhibiting this behavior?

Comment: Do you get an exception on the server side (have you configured your keystore properly)?

Comment: No i don't get any exception, and I don't know what a keystore is. I guess the problem comes from this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bruno gave me the answer in the comments: I haven't configured any keystore.

Comment: So there must have been an exception at the server which you haven't told us about.

Answer (score 2):

'Connection refused' only has two meanings whether plaintext or SSL. There is nothing listening at the ip:port you tried to connect to, or an intermediate firewall explicitly blocked the connect by sending an RST.

Your second line of code creates an SSLServerSocket on an arbitrary port, because you left out the 'port' parameter. That's almost certainly the problem.

Comment: I edited the question to show the next server lines. I stress the fact that this code is working with standard sockets.

Comment: Actually, it can also mean that a firewall actively refused the connection, but that seems unlikely in this case.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart Agreed on both counts.